# Mongoose: Push data to array in for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have small problem i have this code:

```
Messages.findOne({id_user: to}, function (err, toUser) {

                    //dopisujemy wiadomość w tablicy użytkownika
                    var messArray = toUser.messagesArray;
                    //przeszukujemy tablice z wiadomościami aby znaleźć odpowiedniego użytkownika
                    for(var i=0;i<messArray.length; ++i) {
                        if(messArray[i].id_converser = who) {
                            // console.log(messArray[i]);
                            toUser.messagesArray[i].messages.push({id_converser: who,message: message,date: Date()});

                            toUser.save(function (err) {
                                if(err) console.log(err);
                                console.log('Wiadomość dodana');
                            })
                            return;

                        }
                    }



            }) //end zapisujemy wiadomość w miejscu przeznaczenia
```

and everything seems fine, in console i have message "wiadomosc dodana", but when i check it in database i not see this added data, why.
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

In order to push to the array in the actual database you need to use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or something like [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator

Answer (score 0):

When you modify any deep property or array property of an object in JavaScript you need to use isModified method in order to tell Mongoose that a property of the object is modified and update it in the database.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified

So you need to execute it after the push function like that:

`toUser.isModified('messagesArray')`